# install usb wifi card tl-wn823n in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

I tried the commands I found for Ubuntu 16.04 and it doesn't work

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

This is what happened:

```
miguel@miguel-MS-7C52:~$ cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
miguel@miguel-MS-7C52:~/rtl8192eu-linux-driver$ sudo dkms add .
sudo: dkms : commande introuvable
miguel@miguel-MS-7C52:~/rtl8192eu-linux-driver$ sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
sudo: dkms : commande introuvable
miguel@miguel-MS-7C52:~/rtl8192eu-linux-driver$ sudo modprobe 8192eu^C
miguel@miguel-MS-7C52:~/rtl8192eu-linux-driver$
```

Comment: Did you first install dkms? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install DKMS.

```
sudo apt install dkms
```

Comment: Consider explaining why if possible.

Comment: *maybe* because the instructions mention using a dkms command and dkms wasnt installed